# Problem with a table align

Tags: tables

I am trying to insert a 2 column table in my tex file and the result is this:

[image]

```
\documentclass[10pt,a4paper]{book} 
\usepackage{amsmath,amsthm,amsfonts,amssymb,mathtools}
\usepackage{textcomp}
\usepackage{tcolorbox,xcolor}
\usepackage{array}
\usepackage{multirow}
\begin{document}
\begin{tabular}{ |c | c | c | }
\hline
 c1 & c2  \\
\hline
\multirow{1} {4em} 
a & b  \\
a & ad \\
a & a \\
\hline
\end{tabular}
\end{document}
```

Can I ask you how I could fix the align in a'? Also, how could I fix the width in the c2 column?

Thank you in advance.

Comment: Do you want the _a_ in the second row to be centered like the rest? What is multirow being used for? The other issue appears to be that {| c | c | c |} sets up a three-column table, not a two-column one.

Comment: Thanks for the comment. I use multirow because I found it in a prefixed example which I tried to adapt. But the first a is not aligned  in the same line to the others, this is the main problem I can't fix

Comment: Yes but even with {| c | c |} the problem remains

Comment: Just remove `multirow` which seemingly has nothing to do here.

Comment: It works! Thank you very much!

Answer (score 9, accepted):

If I'm understanding your question correctly, then this should do it.

```
\documentclass[10pt,a4paper]{book}
\usepackage{array}

\begin{document}
    \begin{tabular}{ | >{\centering}m{4em} | >{\centering}m{4em} | }
        \hline
        c1 & c2
        \tabularnewline \hline
        a & b
        \tabularnewline
        a & ad
        \tabularnewline
        a & a
        \tabularnewline \hline
    \end{tabular}
\end{document}
```

[image: table]

In the `tabular` environment, you can specify the width of a column using `p{width}`. With the `array` package, you can specify the justification using `>{\command}` before the column. But then you must use `\tabularnewline` instead of `\\`.

Comment: There are excellent tutorials for making tables on [Wikibooks](https://en.wikibooks.org/wiki/LaTeX/Tables) or [Overleaf](https://www.overleaf.com/learn/latex/tables). You can also try this online table generator https://www.tablesgenerator.com.

Comment: Thanks you for your answer, this was what I asked. Tbh  I tried tables generator, but the result was not what I wanted, maybe because of my fault. At any case thanks.

Comment: By loading the `array` package, one has available `w{c}{4em}`, instead of the awkward `>{\centering}m{4em}`; rows can be terminated with ``\\``.

Answer (score 4):

This is what you want, perhaps?

I simplified your preamble: needless to load amsmath when you load `mathtools`, nor amsfonts when you load `amssymb`.

```
\documentclass[10pt,a4paper]{book}
\usepackage{amsthm, amssymb, mathtools}
\usepackage{textcomp}
\usepackage{tcolorbox,xcolor}
\usepackage{array}
\usepackage{multirow}

\begin{document}

\begin{tabular}{ | w{c}{4em}| w{c}{4em}|}
\hline
 c1 & c2 \\
\hline
a & b \\
a & ad \\
a & a \\
\hline
\end{tabular}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Exactly! Many thanks!!!